# Does scrambled screen output mean my onboard graphics is failed?

Tags: boot, graphics-card

My tower has an MSI K9N6PGM2-V2 motherboard with onboard graphics only, with a VGA output and an AMD processor with dedicated fan. A few days ago on boot up the screen out went scrambled (see image below). A ctrl-alt-del reset seemed to fix it but on the next boot up the same problem occurred again but no recovery. Any ideas what to do to fix it? If it could be the graphics then I will try to get a new separate GPU as I could do with getting at least a DVI output for my current monitor. Additionally if I plug that into the available PCIe x16 slot will the CPU recognize it or just continue using the crappy onboard one? I confirmed it's not the monitor by trying an old monitor, which has the same problem.

[image: Image of distorted output]

Comment: just add a link to your image, and someone will edit it in.

Comment: I would definitely look at the graphics card, but being integrated you very likely might have other mobo problems. It will depend on your bios if a new card will work or be blocked. No way to know without either research into the defaults of your mobo or trying it.

Comment: looks most like a video ram issue, with nvidia chipset. are there any adjustments for the way the ram is shared with the video on this type of onboard grafics (vrses onboard get by minor video capability) ?   Try blowing a large fan across the whole board, if that changes something, then it is possible you could "improve" the thermal interface on the chipsets.  You could also play around with the ram, but it would help to know where the screen buffer ram itself is.   Then reset the bios, because it doesnt matter anyways if it isn't going to work, being sure to reset any sata before boot.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely looks like the on-board graphics card is broken.

*Most* BIOS's will automatically detect and default to an add-on graphics card.  If you have a spare one  (or just buy one) you should be able to plug it in and move your monitor to it.

If that doesnt work... hard to tell from your picture if the words are readable.  Can you make out the BIOS text at all?  If so you should be able to switch it to the add-on card.